# Spring Tool Suite 3.6.2 cannot add server adapter Oracle Weblogic Server 10.3.5

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, oracle, weblogic

Can anybody help please? I downloaded Spring Tool Suite 3.6.2 and when I am trying to create a new server runtime environment, it does not list the Oracle folder. I only see listed: 
Apache,
Basic,
ObjectWeb,
Pivotal,
SpringSource,
VMWare.

I went ahead and click on the upper link "Download Additional server adapters" and it lists a couple of new extensions such as:
Geronimo Core Feature...and so on..
JBossAS tools, 
Jonas,
Resin,
SAP,
WASCE...
Websphere

and I still do not see Oracle Weblogic extension.
Am I doing something wrong? 
I already set up my classpath, java_home, Path to where my JDK6 is.
Is there anything else I am missing?

If anybody can guide me where I can find information. I have seen information that says to install Eclipse and STS and Weblogic but I am using directly STS, not Eclipse to develop.

Thanks!

Diana

Comment: I wanted to add a comment that I donwloaded STS and from STS (or Green eclipse) I see the menu choice Eclipse Marketplace and I want to download the Oracle Weblogic from there. Perhaps doing this will allow the Oracle adapter show up in the Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environment -> New Server Runtime Environment.

Answer (score 2):

You can install WebLogic Server adapter from Eclipse Marketplace. Look under Help menu in your Eclipse install. Then search for "WebLogic Server Tools". You will need to know which version of Eclipse STS is based on as there are separate toolsets for Kepler, Luna, etc.

Comment: I have Eclipse Kepler (Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers) and went to Eclipse Marketplace under Help menu as you suggested. I typed STS and found Spring Tool Suite STS for Eclipse Kepler (4.3) 3.6.2 release and I typed "Oracle Weblogic Server Tools" and got back the Oracle WebLogic Server Tools for Kepler so I installed it. So now i will try to start to use it and see how it goes.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: I wanted to add a comment that I donwloaded STS and from STS (or Green eclipse) I see the menu choice Eclipse Marketplace and I want to download the Oracle Weblogic from there. Perhaps doing this will allow the Oracle adapter show up in the Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environment -> New Server Runtime Environment.  And also by the way I did this in regular Eclipse (Kepler) and I see Oracle showing up.
So I would like to try from STS itself.

Comment: ALso, what is the difference among all the Oracle WebLogic server Tools. If I am doing this from STS, it doesn't tell me what STS belongs to. Only the version 3.4.0 release.  How will I know which goes with STS among Luna, Juno, Kepler, etc

Comment: You are going to have to figure out what Eclipse version a particular STS package is based on as the different variants of WLS Tools will not install into the wrong Eclipse version. I asked Google and fairly quickly established that STS 3.4.0 is based on Kepler SR1.

Comment: Look in the 'About Spring Tool Suite' screen. My STS 3.6.3.RELEASE showed the Platform as Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.1) right under the version and build Id.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure %100 but STS might not have weblogic support. If you are determined to use Eclipse, I would suggest Kepler that would come with the recommended oepe bundle :

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/oepe-12121-1981534.html

Comment: Hi, I am grateful for the help but I am not using Eclipse. I am using the Spring Tool Suite which looks like Eclipse but it's for Spring framework. Do you suggest I use Eclipse and install the oepe and set it up to use Spring framework? I have Kepler but I was looking to use the developer environment in STS 3.6.2

Comment: This is a highly subjective issue, but everytime I start a project I first try to find out about the technologies that are going to be used throughout, and decide my ide in final steps. I have been working with weblogic for about 9 months and after having several problems with both eclipse distros ( STS and Kepler alike) I switched to IDEA. This worked for me. I recommend Kepler that comes with the bundle because it is easy to integrate with weblogic however the choice I made for myself was IDEA due to a broader evaluation.

Comment: BTW I believe STS is an eclipse fork of version 4++ so in a way you are using Eclipse, the green eclipse =)

Comment: Thank you @Pumpkin. I really appreciate you taking the time.  
That's right I am using green eclipse. :)So yes, I will have to try to make kepler work then.